# C and C++ syntax highlighting are the same?

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

I have just seen [a discussion with the C language tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35485857/1455631), and C++-only keywords like `try` are highlighted as keywords.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Stack Overflow uses [google prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) for syntax highlighting, which is pretty decent but by no means perfect for lots of languages, considering how small and fast it is.

One of the trade-offs is handling languages with similar syntax together, and ignoring corner-cases and rarely used things altogether.

More in this [faq](/questions/tagged/faq): [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)