# Why are string syntax highlight colors different for C/C++?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, syntax-highlighting

I was looking at two different answers, one C++ and one C, and noticed the color for strings between the two are different colors of red. The C++ is a bright red, a bit harder to read, and the C red is darker, and at least to my eyes looks nore readable and normal. The examples are:

[image]

From [Beginner C++ problem; I am trying to learn about input validation loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406754/beginner-c-problem-i-am-trying-to-learn-about-input-validation-loops)

And then for C:

[image]

From [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c/60409814#60409814)

I understand from reviewing similar questions that google prettify is used and there can be corner-cases where the highlighting differs, e.g. [C and C++ syntax highlighting are the same?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317162/c-and-c-syntax-highlighting-are-the-same). However, for something as common as string-literals, I would expect the color to be the same between both languages.

Is this a deliberate choice that is being made?, or is this just the result of limitations in google prettify?

Comment: Yes, I am also facing the same issue with HTML/CSS code inside snippet, strange new coloration. I thought it was my eyes but seems not ..

Comment: Well, at least that proves I'm not going senile `:)`

Comment: This may have been a caching thing? Both snippets render with the same colours for me. There's been a [recent change to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344238/code-highlighting-colors-were-changed-intentional-or-not/344241#344241) that may have caused the mismatch?

Comment: @Rob Uugh.. But thank you for the link. The new colors are way too bright/saturated. The same color would work if they were desaturated to work on dark backgrounds. I most certainly prefer what the cached image shows compared to the "Electric Red" of the new string color. When you pass 50, you appreciate the old "If it ain't broke -- don't fix it" more and more.

Comment: I guess being over 50 also makes you dislike saturated colors? I kinda like the new saturated colors. Some color pop is nice because it makes them easier to distinguish from the black plain text. The only important thing is sufficient contrast against the background, but...to my eyes, it looks like even the red has that.

Comment: Yes, I'm not against color, but when I put night-view on, the brighter reds really glow against the darker background. Human physiology will accommodate most changes in time until they are no longer noticed. The new palette would have been nice to get the community feedback on. What SO has had has worked so well the past few years, that a change may not always be for the better. At least we know what happened.

Comment: Thank You! Whoever found the happy medium of `#942121` instead of `#C02D2E` for the red did a very good job!