# Formatted code colors have changed, for the worse

Tags: discussion, design, code-formatting

Why have formatted code colors changed within the past 2 days?

Here is an example with the old colors on the left, new on the right

[image]

(Taken from [this question which was asked 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399089/why-does-this-code-work-in-vb-but-not-in-c-sharp-invalidcastexception), and I happened to have a tab still open. I got the screenshot on the left, then refreshed, then got the screenshot on the right.)

Notably, the blue keyword color has become lighter. It has changed from blue to teal. Compare `new AutConnMgr` in the c# example. For me at least, it has become more difficult to distinguish a difference between keyword and class in c#. The VB.NET `Dim x As New` keywords are all also lighter. The string red color has also changed but to no detriment as far as I can tell.

Visual Studio has much more contrast. Compare this screenshot from Visual Studio with the new code above

C# in Visual Studio has better contrast too but doesn't follow SO formatting.

[image]

VB.NET too

[image]

Why was this changed?

Comment: über meta dupe: [Code highlighting colors were changed. Intentional or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344238/363946)

Comment: Related (although their situation was slightly different): [Why are string syntax highlight colors different for C/C++?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394241)

Comment: And I’ll put the link here as well: I [created a codepen comparing the old and new](https://codepen.io/mjpieters/details/LYVWGLZ) (and added a few other schemes).